Why sometimes a paper containing old references is considered not ready for publication and sometimes not?
I was wondering if there are research papers that have references that are old (i.e., ten or more years old) and reviewers of those papers have recommended acceptance, but when you want to publish a paper and it passes initial screening of a reputable journal and is in peer review process, it faces rejection because of having old references.
What could be the reason for this? Is it a universal criterion to reject a paper containing old references or it is the personal decision of reviewer?

Well, if there was other work in that decade that you did not reference that’s a problem.

@Daniel Hatton, only old references.

Your question is hard to understand. What do you mean by reviewers recommended acceptance, and then it went to initial review and then peer review, where it faced rejection?

I think you might be misunderstanding the meaning of "references are old" in a peer review; the reviewer likely isn't bothered that you have some old references, they're bothered that you're lacking more recent ones.

Reviewers and editors accept or reject papers based on a holistic view. That includes, but is not limited to, whether the references you have adequately represent the state of knowledge in the field. In some fields, things that were done a decade or more ago are what the current state of the art is, in others it is not. In any case, this is only one part of many that is considered in determining the fate; your paper won't get accepted only because you have an up-to-date literature review, but may get rejected for that reason.
